# Verifying that an integral exists with a singularity at the origin.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

If $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does it make integral sense of type $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}\frac{1}{|\xi|}\widehat{f}(\xi)\,d\xi$? (I ask this because of the possible problem at $\xi=0$)

The reason for my question is due to the fact that the equation

$$ (1-\Delta)u=f$$
has the solution
$$u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+|\xi|^2}\widehat{f}(\xi)\right)$$
(or $u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}\frac{1}{1+|\xi|^2}\widehat{f}(\xi)\,d\xi$)

Comment: $\frac{1}{|\xi|}\widehat{f}(\xi)$ need not even be locally integrable. so its FT is not defined.

Comment: and is there some reason why $1+|\xi|^2$ works but $|\xi|$ doesn't? Or is it only because of the problem at the origin?

Comment: $\frac 1 {1+|\xi|^{2}}$ is bounded near the origin, $\frac 1 {\xi}$ is not.

Comment: It also decays faster for large $\xi$ ...

Answer (score 1):

If $\widehat f\in L^{p_0'} \cap L^{p_1'}$ with $p_0<n<p_1$ (so in dimension $n>1$), then your integral make sense. Writing
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n} \left|\frac{e^{ix\cdot\xi}}{|\xi|}\,\widehat f(\xi)\right|\mathrm d\xi = \int_{|\xi|\leq 1} \frac{|\widehat f(\xi)|}{|\xi|}\mathrm d\xi + \int_{|\xi|\geq 1} \frac{|\widehat f(\xi)|}{|\xi|}\mathrm d\xi
$$
and using Hölder's inequality for both integrals yields
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n} \left|\frac{e^{ix\cdot\xi}}{|\xi|}\,\widehat f(\xi)\right|\mathrm d\xi \leq C_0 \,\|\widehat f(\xi)\|_{L^{p_0'}} + C_1 \,\|\widehat f(\xi)\|_{L^{p_1'}}
$$
with $C_0 = \left(\int_{|\xi|\leq 1} |\xi|^{-p_0}\,\mathrm d \xi\right)^{1/p_0} < \infty$ if $p_0 <n$, and $C_1 = \left(\int_{|\xi|\leq 1} |\xi|^{-p_1}\,\mathrm d \xi\right)^{1/p_0} < \infty$ if $p_1> n$.

Notice that the singularity at the origin is dealt by the index $p_0$. But if $f\in L^{p_0}$ with $p_0\in[1,2]$, then $\widehat f\in L^{p_0'}$ by the Hausdorff–Young inequality.

So, the true problem is actually the decay of $1/|\xi|$ for large values of $\xi$. This prevents to define your integral as a classical Lebesgue convergent integral.

---

However, in the distributional sense, there is not problem to define the inverse Fourier transform of $|\xi|^{-1}\,\widehat{f}(\xi)$, and it is nothing but
$$
\mathcal F(|\xi|^{-1}\,\widehat{f}(\xi))(x) = C_n\,(-\Delta)^{-1/2}f(x) = c_n\int_{\Bbb R^n} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-1}} \mathrm d y.
$$
This expression is well defined a.e. if $f\in L^p$ with $p\in(1,n)$ by the Hardy–Littlewood–Sobolev inequality, and more precisely
$$
\|(-\Delta)^{-1/2}f\|_{L^q} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}
$$
with $q = \frac{np}{n-p}$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is an answer I was waiting for. I will try to understand it line by line. In which reference could I find the arguments of your comment? it is interesting

Comment: Any good book of analysis '^^ For example the book by Lieb and Loss, you will find all the inequalities I use.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In this reference the argument is shown that you say? or only estimates? I'm interested in this

Comment: Which part are you missing?

Comment: In the definition 
$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^{-1} \widehat{f}(\xi))(x)=c_n \int \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-1}}\,dy$
Why?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transform, and then the Fourier transform of $1/|x|$ is given for example in Theorem 5.9 of the book I mentioned

Comment: $\langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^{-1} \widehat{f}(\xi)),\phi\rangle=\langle f,\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^{-1}\widehat{\phi}(\xi))\rangle$
now,  $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^{-1}\widehat{\phi}(\xi)) =c_n\int \frac{\phi(y)}{|x-y|^{n-1}}\,dy$?